# How to understand the meaningless Swift stack traces?

Tags: ios, swift

Getting the following stack trace from Crashlytics.

Code that is crashing is `return string`

```
extension UserVisit: DashboardItem {

    public var dashboardItemAttributedTitle: NSAttributedString {
        let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(withUser.publicName) (\(withUser.publicAddress.fullDescription))", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.regularLight()])
        string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.regularBold(), range: NSMakeRange(0 , count(withUser.publicName)))
        return string  /*  Crash points to this line of code */
    }

}
```

The code points to the return statement. The only reason I can think of for this crash is `string` being nil, which is not possible because if it was nil it would have crashed on the line above when `addAttribute` was called. Getting lots of these crashes and the stacktrace says absolutely nothing about what's causing it

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Company                   0x00000001001c05c0 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Company.UserVisit.dashboardItemAttributedTitle.getter : ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString (DashboardItemExtensions.swift:122)
1  Company                   0x00000001001be674 @objc Company.UserVisit.dashboardItemAttributedTitle.getter : ObjectiveC.NSAttributedString (DashboardItemExtensions.swift)
2  Company                   0x00000001001d3618 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Company.DashboardItemCell.configure (Company.DashboardItemCell)(Company.DashboardItem) -> () (DashboardItemCell.swift:93)
3  Company                   0x00000001001d100c Company.DashboardItemCell.configure (Company.DashboardItemCell)(Company.DashboardItem) -> () (DashboardItemCell.swift)
4  Company                   0x0000000100163cb4 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[2] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Company.DashboardViewController.collectionView (Company.DashboardViewController)(ObjectiveC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UICollectionViewCell (DashboardViewController.swift:567)
5  Company                   0x000000010015f3b8 @objc Company.DashboardViewController.collectionView (Company.DashboardViewController)(ObjectiveC.UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UICollectionViewCell (DashboardViewController.swift)
6  UIKit                          0x0000000187650710 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 284
7  UIKit                          0x0000000187c7a850 __51-[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate]_block_invoke1381 + 480
8  UIKit                          0x00000001877c5164 -[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate] + 2892
9  UIKit                          0x0000000187c7b694 -[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:] + 1948
10 UIKit                          0x0000000187c79c30 -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:] + 10120
11 UIKit                          0x0000000187c7c988 -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:] + 352
12 Company                   0x000000010016c214 Company.DashboardViewController.((fetchAndPopulateDashboard in _59C7F3AF672DD71404DED200B8F15814) (Company.DashboardViewController) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (DashboardViewController.swift:370)
13 Company                   0x00000001000e1728 Company.BaseNetworkManager.(fetchObject (Company.BaseNetworkManager) -> <A>(A.Type, path : Swift.String, method : Company.Method, parameters : Swift.Optional<Swift.Dictionary<ObjectiveC.NSObject, Swift.AnyObject>>, errorHandler : Company.NetworkErrorHandler, completion : (Company.SingleNetworkResponse<A>) -> ()) -> Company.RequestMirror).(closure #1).(closure #1).(closure #1) (BaseNetworkManager.swift:219)
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194e6d994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194e6d954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000194e7220c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
17 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b2b7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b298a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
19 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a552d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
20 GraphicsServices               0x000000018c4b36fc GSEventRunModal + 168
21 UIKit                          0x0000000187652f40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
22 Company                   0x000000010003ac1c main (main.m:13)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000194e9aa08 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range for an attributed string must be in UTF-16 units.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? The code doesn't always crash. I can't event reproduce the crash. The logs are from a crash reporting tool. And the crash is not on that line either, it's on the line below

Comment: Attributed strings are based on Objective-C strings. Objective-C strings use UTF-16. Ranges for attributed strings must count characters in UTF-16 units. Your code counts whatever units String uses. Crashes will happen depending on what characters you have and how the counts differ.

Comment: Thanks, will make the change and see if I get this crash again or not